# Delete the line with a sepific occurance pattern in SED?

Tags: bash, sed, text-processing

Please spend a few second. i would like to delete the line which has the sixth `<ul>` occurance.
 i google the way of doing it and i tried

`sed -i '/^<ul>$/ d/6' file` .

However, it turn out a

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 9: extra characters after
```

error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK you can't do that easily with `sed`. You can do that like joining all the lines to one string, then delete that 6th occurence, then split the string, but it's easier with `awk`:

```
awk '/<ul>/ {ul++} ul == 6 { getline } 1' INPUTFILE > TMPFILE && mv TMPFILE INPUTFILE
```

Test results are here: https://ideone.com/3YpVu

*Note*: it discards the whole line with the 6th `<ul>`, and assumes that there are only one `<ul>` can be found per line.

HTH

Comment: can adding something to make it not showing the result(html code)??
thanks

Comment: Sorry, could  you be more specific? What are you expecting?

Comment: Sorry for making you confusing. The result is correct 
however, i would like the shell not showing the text file after i modify it

Comment: when i run this , the content of the file will display in the shell

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/<ul>/ && ++count == 6 {next} {print}' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

`perl -p -i -e "s/^<perl-regex-here>$\n//g" <filename>` should get rid of any line matching the perl regular expression you give on any modern unix system. Otherwise, if you are counting occurences and kill the line with the 6th occurrence of , I know of no command that will do that in one line.